# Indirekte Rede im Indikativ

Tags: english-to-german, usage, grammaticality, standard-german, time

Wie ich im Internet und im Buch gelesen habe, benutzt man den Konjunktiv 1 und 2, wenn man das Gesagte wiedergeben will. Ich habe auch gelesen, dass man zum selben Zweck in der gesprochenen Sprache auch den Indikativ benutzen kann.

Kontext: Ich beherrsche die Grammatik der indirekten Rede noch nicht vollständig und ich bin zur Zeit nur zur Hälfte auf dem Niveau von B2. Also beschäftige ich mich im Allgemeinen nicht so viel mit der Grammatik, mit  Strukturen wie dieser (Indirekte Rede mit K1 & K2). Ich benutze bisher immer den Indikativ, um das Gesagte wiederzugeben. Und allgemein wird diese Schreibweise als richtig betrachtet, weil wir so eine komplizierte Grammatik noch nicht gelernt haben.

Also, meine Fragen für euch sind:

1. Darf man eigentlich zur Wiedergabe einer Aussage/Frage/Aufforderung den Indikativ benutzen, wie ich ihn immer benutzt habe, wenn man immer noch auf der unteren-mittleren Stufe ist?
2. (Diese Frage ist die wichtigste für mich.) Wenn man so (im Indikativ) schreibt, ist es richtig, dass man das Gesagte immer in der sozusagen "originalen" Zeitform wiedergeben muss, unabhängig davon, in welcher Zeitform der "jetzt" Satz (wie man denkt/sagt/bittet) eigentlich ist? Ich frage, weil es auf Englisch anders konstruiert wird, und ich möchte gerne wissen, ob es auf Deutsch auch der Fall ist. Hier meine ich das "Backshifting".

"In English grammar, backshift is the changing of a present tense to a past tense following a past form of a reporting verb. Also known as the sequence-of-tense rule. Backshift (or backshifting) may also occur when a verb in a subordinate clause is affected by the past tense in the main clause." (https://www.thoughtco.com/backshift-sequence-of-tense-rule-in-grammar-1689017)

Gibt es auch "Backshifting" in der deutschen Sprache? Benutzt man das?

Beispiele, die diese Frage erklären können:

Welche Sätze sind die richtigen?

Auf Englisch sagt man : "I thought I **was** the only one who **could** see the ghosts."

Sagt man auf Deutsch: "Ich dachte, dass ich der einzige **bin**, der die Geister sehen **kann**." oder "Ich dachte, dass ich der einzige **war**, der die Geister sehen **konnte**." ?

"Ich hatte überhaupt keine Ahnung, wie ich die Situation verbessern **kann**." oder "Ich hatte überhaupt keine Ahnung, wie ich die Situation verbessern **konnte**."?

"Ich wusste gar nicht, wer der alte Mann **ist**." oder "Ich wusste gar nicht, wer der alte Mann **war**."?

"Er hat mir gesagt, dass ich nicht am Handy spielen **kann**." oder "Er hat mir gesagt, dass ich nicht am Handy spielen **konnte**."?

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt im Deutschen kein "Backshifting" wie im Englischen. Es sieht aber manchmal so aus, weil die Formen des Konjunktiv II teilweise mit denen des Präteritums identisch sind.

Du kannst auch den Indikativ in der indirekten Rede verwenden, allerdings machst du dir damit die Sicht der zitierten Person zu eigen.

---

> Er hat mir gesagt, dass ich nicht am Handy spielen **kann**.

Du akzeptierst das als Tatsache. Du spielst nicht am Handy.

> Er hat mir gesagt, dass ich nicht am Handy spielen **könne**.

Du gibst ihn nur wieder. Du spielst z.B. gerade am Handy, um das Gegenteil zu beweisen.

> Ich dachte, dass ich der einzige **bin**, der die Geister sehen kann.

Hier zitierst du ohnehin deine eigenen Gedanken. Der Indikativ ist daher angemessen und auch gebräuchlich.

> Ich dachte, dass ich der einzige **sei**, der die Geister sehen kann.

Mit der Verwendung des Konjunktiv I trittst du hinter deine eigenen Gedanken einen Schritt zurück. Du zitierst dich nur noch selbst, hältst das Gesagte aber nicht mehr für eine unumstößliche Tatsache. Die meisten Deutschsprecher werden diesen Satz daher genauso verstehen wie den folgenden:

> Ich dachte, dass ich der einzige **wäre**, der die Geister sehen kann.

Mit der Verwendung des Konjunktiv II ziehst du deinen vorherigen Gedankengang unmissverständlich in Zweifel. Dir wurde kurz zuvor offensichtlich das Gegenteil bewiesen.

---

> Ich wusste gar nicht, wer der alte Mann ist.

Hier ist ausschließlich der Indikativ richtig, denn etwas zu wissen erlaubt keine Zweifel, ebensowenig wie das zweifellose Nichtwissen keine zweifelnde Aussage erlaubt. Ausnahme:

> Ich **wüsste** (nicht), was ich **täte**.
>
> Ich **wüsste** (nicht), was ich schenken **könnte/sollte/müsste**.

Verwendet man den Konjunktiv II im Zusammenhang mit wissen und tun/machen oder Modalausdrücken, sucht man Rat oder gibt diesen. Das Wissen wird ebenfalls in den Konjunktiv II gesetzt, denn man befindet sich ja gar nicht wirklich in der Situation.

Aber Vorsicht: Es ist häufig unerwünschter Rat.

> Ich hatte überhaupt keine Ahnung, wie ich die Situation verbessern **kann**.

Auch hier ist wieder nur der Indikativ richtig.

> Ich **hätte** überhaupt keine Ahnung, wie ich die Situation verbessern **könnte**.

Gleiches Spiel wie oben mit *wissen*. Du suchst Rat.

Comment: Danke für Ihre Antwort @Janka ! Ich möchte noch fragen, was ich tun muss, oder welcher Regel ich folgen muss, wenn ich überhaupt auf den Konjunktiv 1 und 2 verzichten und ausschließlich im Indikativ schreiben will. Sie sind mir einfach zu kompliziert! Gibt es so eine Regel? z.B konsistent mit der Zeitform zu sein? Außerdem würdest du auch sagen, dass die anderen Sätze, die im Präteritum geschrieben wurden, auch richtig sein können? bzw. ("Ich dachte, dass ich der einzige war, der die Geister sehen konnte." ,  "Ich wusste gar nicht, wer der alte Mann war." , usw.) ?

Comment: ich verstehe, warum  "Er hat mir gesagt, dass ich nicht am Handy spielen konnte." falsch ist, aber die anderen Sätze scheinen mir richtig zu sein.

Comment: Du kannst nicht auf Konjunktiv I und II verzichten, weil das dann grundsätzlich so verstanden wird, dass du das Zitierte selbst als Fakt ansiehst. Es handelt sich nicht um ein grammatisches, sondern um ein semantisches Problem.

Comment: Die Sätze im Präteritum drücken genau dasselbe wie die Sätze im Präsens aus, nur eben in der **Erzählzeit** einer Geschichte. Die Sätze mit der Mischung aus Präteritum und Präsens sind nur dann richtig, wenn das Präteritum als **Ersatzform** für das Perfekt angenommen wird. Das kommt im Norddeutschen häufig vor, im Süddeutschen hingegen nur für die Hilfsverben.

Comment: Wenn die Konjunktive später letztendlich notwendig sind, werde ich sie auf jeden Fall benutzen. Ich meinte, was ich in der "kurz" entfernten Zukunft machen kann und soll. Übrigens, meinst du, dass die oben genannten Sätze auch richtig sein können? Ich schwöre, dass ich viele Texte gesehen habe, die so einer "Regel" folgen (im Allgemeinen einfach konsistent mit der Zeitform zu sein). Tut mir leid, dass ich so viel frage. Dieses neue Konzept verwirrt mich sehr.

Comment: In dieser Webseite zum Beispiel wird dieser "Regel" gefolgt. (https://starke-gedanken.de/ich-wusste-dass-er-fehler-hatte-aber-ich-wusste-nicht-dass-er-ein-narzisst-war/)

Comment: Indikativ, Konjunktiv I und Konjunktiv II sind keine Zeitformen, sondern drücken aus, was du für eine Tatsache, für Hörensagen und für pure Fantasie hältst. Die meisten Menschen machen sich Hörensagen einfach zu schnell zu eigen.

Comment: Ach so! Das habe ich nicht gewusst. Hat das also nichts mit der Zeitform nicht zu tun? Was dieses Thema angeht, habe ich immer gedacht, dass ich einfach "konsistent mit der Zeitform" sein muss. Es sei denn, dass der Satz sehr komisch aussieht, wenn ich mich zwinge, konsistent zu bleiben. z.B Ich würde sagen : "Ich wusste nicht, dass er ein Feind war!" aber ich würde nicht sagen : "Ich hatte keine Ahnung, wie man einen Lebenslauf schrieb/schreiben konnte", weil der Satz keinen Sinn macht, denn der Nebensatz bezieht sich meiner meinung Nach nicht auf ein "relevantes" Ereignis.

Comment: Diese Autorin verwendet durchgehend das Präteritum, was für eine Erzählung auch üblich ist. An einer Stelle hat das Lektorat versagt: *Ich habe mich immer wieder damit abgefunden* – hier muss *hatte* stehen, weil das Plusquamperfekt das Vergangenheitskomplement des Präteritums ist, und nicht das Perfekt.

Comment: Ah kann man also für eine Erzählung konsistent bleiben? Das sehe ich auch so, weil ich immer mit dieser "Methode" geschrieben habe. Ich denke auch, dass "Ich habe mich immer wieder damit abgefunden" schon okay ist, weil es im gleichen Kontext steht und immer noch Sinn macht oder? Sonst würde jeder Text, in dem das Präteritum benutzt wird, das Plusquamperfekt benutzen.

Comment: Nein, denn aus dem Zusammenhang erkennt man, dass dieser Satz ein Teil der Erzählung ist. Ja, Texte, die das Präteritum als Gegenwart der Erzählzeit verwenden, müssen das Plusquamperfekt als Vergangenheit dieser Erzählzeit verwenden. Es ist möglich, das Präteritum zur Beschreibung der Vergangenheit der Realität zu verwenden, allerdings ist das ein weitgehend norddeutsches Phänomen.

Comment: "Er hat mir gesagt, dass ich nicht am Handy spielen kann." ist als Tatsachenbehauptung unüblich. Es ist eine verbreitete Fehlbildung für "nicht spielen darf". Es könnte auch gemeint sein, dass dem Betroffenen das nötige Geschick abgesprochen wird, wie in "Susi kann keine Witze erzählen". Aber eine Zustimmung wird so oder so nicht zum Ausdruck gebracht.